# GTK Window DeleteEvent not firing

Tags: events, mono, gtk

I have a custom GTK window. I am trying to hook into the DeleteEvent, either using MonoDevelop or "by hand", by simply adding an event handler to the DeleteEvent event.

However, the event is not firing when I click the "X" button on the top right hand corner of the window (the close button, if you will).

Why? This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was disposing of the window instance before the events had time to fire.

If I had to describe GTK in one word, it would be "***ambiguous***".

Personally, I would expect an exception to be thrown when an event is suppose to be fired against a disposed object. Likewise, I would expect the window to be hidden (or destroyed) when it is disposed. Neither of these are the case.

Lesson Learned.

Comment: Keep in mind that GTK# is a .NET wrapper around GTK+, and that GTK+ keeps their object with counted references. So when you dispose you managed object the reference count is just dropped (and the signals are disconnected!), but the window itself is not destroyed until that reference reaches 0. It will not reach 0 because it is realized in the screen, and the  window manager holds one reference. It is like a file: a file in the filesystem does not disappear just by disposing your `System.IO.File` object; you have to call `Delete`. Likewise the window will be around until you call `destroy`.

Comment: Sure, but as you've said, it's a .NET wrapper around GTK+. I want .NET standard error handling included in that wrapper. Otherwise, I might as well just write my own wrapper. And how come the window doesn't destroy itself when dispose is called? In what instance would you want the window to be visible while disposed?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, Dispose is not the same as Destroy. It's like having a handle to a file, here you have a handle to a window.

Comment: Dispose is used to release managed and unmanaged resources when called from user code. That is the IDisposable implementation pattern suggested by Microsoft. I am simply stating that GTK# should implement the standard Microsoft IDisoposable implementation pattern, and dispose of both managed and unmanaged resources (including the window handle for which it contains a reference) when calling dispose. Is it debatable that that would be a Microsoft standard best practice?

Comment: @rodrigo, I know how GTK# windows work. I am suggesting that they should *not* work that way. GTK+ may work in whichever way it pleases, according to C/C++ standards of coding. To be taken seriously as a .NET library, GTK# *should* conform to Microsoft best practices, unless it has a very good reason not to.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, actually, IDisposable is only for unmanaged resources, not managed, that is the GC's job.  Disposing an object in the way you say would swipe it from under the feet of the supporting library, this is a wrapper around unmanaged code, the rules are written by the unmanaged library, not the wrapper.

Comment: @IanNorton, The GC's job is not the disposal of managed resources, it is the *collection* (and, *possibly*, finalization) of managed resources. Disposing of managed resources is still left up to user code. Examine the following scenario: You create an object (A) which subscribes to an event of another object (B). You then lose the reference to object A, and yet object B still has a reference to object A through the event delegate. Who is responsible for disposing of that resource? Not the GC. It is the developers responsibility to handle this scenario.

Comment: @IanNorton, see here for more information about IDisposable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx . Now, as far as the window handle goes, that IS an unmanaged resource, and SHOULD be disposed of by Dispoes(), even by your definition. Take a look at the standard window's Form class. What does it do when disposed of? What disadvantage does it have of closing the window upon disposal?